# No dibuja google.map.Circle en google.visualization.Map

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, google-chart-api

estoy desarroyando una aplicación web en laravel y debo visualizar un mapa con marcadores, circulos, etc. Además uso google charts y tengo unas tablas. Cuando pulso sobre una tabla me selecciona el marcador cuya posición equivale a la posicion que tengo guardada e la tabla (por eso google.visualiazation.Map me va perfecto para hacer eso). El problema es que a la hora de dibujar circulos sobre el mapa no lo puedo hacer sobre google.visualization.Map, sólo puedo sobre la api google.maps.Map. Cual es exactamente la diferencia entre los dos?

Este es mi codigo js que tengo en la view y no me escribe ningún circulo:

```
    var geo = {!! $geofences !!}
    var dev = {!! $devices !!}

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var GeofencesTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    GeofencesTable.addColumn('string', 'name');
    GeofencesTable.addColumn('number', 'radius');
    GeofencesTable.addColumn('string', 'latitude');
    GeofencesTable.addColumn('string', 'longitude');
    GeofencesTable.addColumn('string', 'emails');
    GeofencesTable.addColumn('string', 'created_at');
    GeofencesTable.addColumn('string', 'updated_at');

    for (var i = 0; i < geo.length; i++) {
        GeofencesTable.addRows([
            [geo[i].name, geo[i].radius, geo[i].latitude, geo[i].longitude, geo[i].emails, geo[i].created_at, geo[i].updated_at]
        ]);
    }

    var tableGeo = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_geo'));
    tableGeo.draw(GeofencesTable, {showRowNumber: false});

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var DevicesTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    DevicesTable.addColumn('string', 'name');
    DevicesTable.addColumn('string', 'alias');
    DevicesTable.addColumn('number', 'battery');
    DevicesTable.addColumn('string', 'latitude');
    DevicesTable.addColumn('string', 'longitude');
    DevicesTable.addColumn('string', 'created_at');
    DevicesTable.addColumn('string', 'updated_at');

    var mapData = [['Lat', 'Lon', 'Description']];

    for (var i = 0; i < dev.length; i++) {
        DevicesTable.addRows([
            [dev[i].name, dev[i].alias, dev[i].battery, dev[i].latitude, dev[i].longitude, dev[i].created_at, dev[i].updated_at]
        ]);
        mapData.push([parseFloat(dev[i].latitude), parseFloat(dev[i].longitude), 'Battery: ' + dev[i].battery + ', Last movement: ' + dev[i].last_movement]);
    }

    var tableDev = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_dev'));
    tableDev.draw(DevicesTable, {showRowNumber: false});

    var Info = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);

    var geoView = new google.visualization.DataView(Info);

    var options = {
        showTooltip: true,
        showInfoWindow: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        icons: {
        default: {
            normal: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/48/map-marker-icon.png',
            selected: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Azure-icon.png'
        }

        },
    };

    var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
    map.draw(geoView, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(tableDev, 'select',
        function() {
            map.setSelection(tableDev.getSelection());
        });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(tableGeo, 'select',
        function() {
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41, -1),
            radius: 500000
            });
        });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(map, 'select',
        function() {
            tableDev.setSelection(map.getSelection());
        });
```

Porque no me dibuja el circulo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: La api visualization de google sirve para generar gráficas estadísticas mientras que maps es para representación geográfica, mapas como los de [Maps](https://www.google.com/maps)

Comment: entonces no puedo dibujar circulos en un gooogle.visualization.Map?

Comment: Sí, claro. Visualization sirve para gráficos de todo tipo: de barras, círculos y también tiene la posibilidad de combinarse con maps para mostrar gráficos en un mapa geográfico con colores y demás. Aquí tienes todo lo que se puede hacer con visualization y charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Comment: de acuerdo, entonces que tengo mal en mi codigo para que no me esté dibujando el circulo en mi google.visualization.map?

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que el título del post no es nada acertado... Hay que cambiarlo para que se ajuste a lo que realmente necesitas, que es ver por qué no te dibuja

Comment: Cambia el título del post para que se ajuste más a lo que necesitas realmente, que es saber por qué no te pinta. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es añadir un fragmento de css/html/javascript que sea funcional sobre el que podamos probar. Tienes la opción en el editor de stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según yo, el mapa no necesita un `DataView`, sino que basta la salida del `arrayToDataTable`

```
var Info = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(mapData);

var options = {
    showTooltip: true,
    showInfoWindow: true,
    useMapTypeControl: true,
    icons: {
    default: {
        normal: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/48/map-marker-icon.png',
        selected: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Azure-icon.png'
    }

    },
};

var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
map.draw(Info, options);
```

Pero como sea, para dibujar un círculo, no te sirve asignarle como mapa una instancia de `google.visualization.Map`. Tiene que ser una instancia de `google.maps.Map`.

Con tu enfoque, lo más que puedes hacer en tu caso es crear un tipo custom de marker (con un ícono que sea un círculo) y asignar ese tipo de marker a ciertas filas.

Por ejemplo:

```
var coords = [
            ['Lat', 'Long', 'Description', 'Marker'],
            [37.4232, -122.0853, 'Work', 'blue'],
            [37.4289, -122.1697, 'University', 'green'],
            [37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport', 'pink'],
            [37.4422, -122.1731, 'Shopping', null]
        ];
        var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';


        var Info = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(coords);

        var options = {
            zoomLevel: 10,
            showTooltip: true,
            showInfoWindow: true,
            useMapTypeControl: true,
            icons: {
                blue: {
                    normal: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
                    selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
                },
                green: {
                    normal: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
                    selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png'
                },
                pink: {
                    normal: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png',
                    selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Pink-icon.png'
                }
            }
        };
        var geoView = new google.visualization.DataView(Info);
        map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        map.draw(geoView, options);
```

Y en el evento `select` añadir un elemento a `coords`, volver a declarar Info, volver a declarar `geoView` y volver a llamar a `map.draw()` con el nuevo `geoView`.

**Una segunda opción**, es que incluyas el script de Google Maps API, cosa que el objeto `google.maps` quede en tu ámbito global, y dibujar tú mismo el mapa, usando `new google.maps.Map(<container>,<options>)` y luego añadiendo los markers uno a uno instanciando nuevos `google.maps.Marker`. Lo malo de este enfoque es que pinchando en filas de la tabla el mapa no va a reaccionar, ni viceversa. No van a estar bindeados entre sí.

Vas a tener que darle un identificador a tus markers que calce con el ID de cada fila de tu datatable, y manipular los estados tal que pinchando la tabla se modifique el estilo de los markers cuya propiedad `id` calce con el id de la fila que pinchaste, y viceversa.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando y, si te fijas, es bastante artesanal bindear los eventos entre el mapa y el datatable:

https://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/4ek7Lwrn/29/

Ojo, necesitas un API key para el mapa. El que está en el ejemplo sólo funciona en JSFiddle.

Comment: esta parte es la parte de window content que me visualiza esta información al clickar sobre cada marker (esto en principio me lo esta haciendo bien). Lo que no me esta dibujando es el google.maps.Circle que esta dentro del listener de la tablaGeo.

Comment: Sí, edité mi respuesta. Había entendido mal la pregunta. En resumen, así como lo está haciendo no se puede. A lo más puedes declarar tus puntos con un atributo `Marker`, declarar un tipo de marker cuyo ícono sea un círculo, y  añadirle markers a tu `arrayToDataTable` que tengan como  `Marker` el nombre del tipo de marker cuyo ícono es un círculo, y entonces volver a invocar `map.draw`.

Comment: de acuerdo entonces si quisiera tener las ventajas de google.maps.Map debería de alguna manera obtener las coordenadas de la fila seleccionada, encontrar y seleccionar en el mapa el marcador con las coordenadas que se correspondan. No hay algún método o manera mas simple verdad? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Te dejé un ejemplo funcionando en https://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/4ek7Lwrn/29/
 donde básicamente creas un array de markers, y su índice coincide con la fila del datatable. Pero además le doy una propiedad `index` de modo que al pinchar sobre el marker sepa explícitamente su lugar dentro del array. En ese mapa, si pinchas en un marker se activa la fila y viceversa. Y si pinchas en el mapa mismo, se crea un círculo.

Comment: perfecto mil gracias!